# Ubuntu server 11.04 в VMware и ssh

Tags: putty, ssh, vmware, ubuntu

Собственно запустил ubuntu server в vmware, установил openssh-server, включил, проверил его набрав в консоли ssh localhost - работает. Запустил из-под Windows 7 PuTTy, пытаюсь подключиться, вводя свой IP, но мне пишет следующее:

> "network error: connection refused".

Интернет на виртуальную машину раздается через NAT.

Comment: Посмотрите похожие вопросы: http://hashcode.ru/questions/487/ и http://hashcode.ru/questions/2652/

Comment: смотрел, но там другие ситуации =(

Comment: Еще вариант - ssh по localhost доступен, т.к. такова политика файрволла или этот адрес внесен в белый список для ssh. А остальные адреса, откуда некто будет коннектиться к ssh, могут быть запрещены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете подключаться так. Вы должны указывать тот ip-адрес, который виртуальная машина выдаст для вашей машины. VMWare создаёт сеть между вашей реальной машиной и виртуальной системой.. и вы должны указать ip-адрес из этой внутренней сети.. либо настроить сетевой мост соответствующим образом.

Comment: Можно по подробнее на счет сетевого моста? ;)

Comment: все, спасибо! 
p.s. разобрался сам ;)